# kotlin- PaymentSessionConfiguration

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments, stripes, companion-object

Hello I am trying to update stripe but when I have to call PaymentSessionConfig my code blocks because the companion of the PaymentSessionConfig class is in private, I cannot modify the class because it is in read only, here is the line :

```
mPaymentSession = PaymentSession (activity = summaryActivity, config = PaymentSessionConfig)
```

and the error message I have :

```
Cannot access 'Companion': it is private in 'PaymentSessionConfig'
Type mismatch.
Required:
PaymentSessionConfig
Found:
PaymentSessionConfig.Companion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share the details of what versions of the SDK you're updating from and to? The [migration docs](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/MIGRATING.md) cover a lot of details changes for various versions.

Is it possible you mean to reference some `paymentSessionConfig`, or what is your `config` here?

See this example implementation using the `PaymentSessionConfig.Builder()` ([github](https://github.com/stripe-samples/sample-store-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/samplestore/PaymentActivity.kt#L61-L70))

Comment: ok thanks this example help me to resolve this issues